# Python script creating anki flashcards using genanki (Expected str instance, dict found ERROR)

Tags: python, pandas, google-translate, anki, pydictionary

The program takes a list of English words written in the first column of an excel file named "List" using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), the headline of the column is "words" and the words are located in "Sheet1".

The words are then stored as a list of strings.

[PyDictionary](https://pypi.org/project/PyDictionary/) and [Googletrans](http://py-googletrans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#api-guide) are utilized by creating *dictionary* and *translator* where the translator is called by translations in order to translate the words from the list into the destination language "Danish".

A simple for loop is then created where every translation in the list of translated words is printed with its origin -> its destination and its definition.

This is presented in the code below:

```
from googletrans import Translator
import pandas as pd
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary

# Load excel file and parse the list of words as strings
file_location = "/Users/.../List.xlsx"
xl_workbook = pd.ExcelFile(file_location)
df = xl_workbook.parse("Sheet1")
aList = df['words'].tolist()
[str(i) for i in aList]

# Use PyDictionary to load definitions of words
dictionary = PyDictionary()

# Translate the list of strings into target language and give definitions
translator = Translator()
translations = translator.translate(aList, dest='da')

# Simple for-loop printing the words
for translation in translations:
    print(
        translation.origin, ' -> ', translation.text,
        dictionary.meaning(translation.origin)
    )
```

This program actually runs and produced the result I wished. However, the problem occurs in the next step as explained here:

I wish to input the words into my favorite flash-card program [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/). Anki is written in Python and has an un-official distribution named [Genanki](https://github.com/kerrickstaley/genanki). However, this is when I encounter my issues.

I now add the following 4 things to my code above:

1. I define my_model as proposed by genanki and create a simple model of a flashcard. This includes a random hardcoded number (which Anki requires), a name of the model, some fields and a template for the card type.
2. I define my_deck as the specific deck of flashcards with a hardcoded random number and a name.
3. I change my for loop to now run the translations and definitions directly into a variable named aNote which consists of the genanki.note operator iterating over the translations each time adding the note to my_deck.
4. I write my anki-file that I can open with Anki.

This can be seen in the code below:

```
from googletrans import Translator
import pandas as pd
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
import genanki

# Load excel file and parse the list of words as strings
file_location = "/Users/.../List.xlsx"
xl_workbook = pd.ExcelFile(file_location)
df = xl_workbook.parse("Sheet1")
aList = df['words'].tolist()
[str(i) for i in aList]

# Use PyDictionary to load definitions of words
dictionary = PyDictionary()

# Use genanki to define a flashcard model
my_model = genanki.Model(
    2042686211,
    'Simple Model',
    fields=[
        {'name': 'Question'},
        {'name': 'Answer'},
    ],
    templates=[
        {
            'name': 'Card 1',
            'qfmt': '{{Question}}',
            'afmt': '{{FrontSide}}<hr id="answer">{{Answer}}',
        },
    ])

# Specify the deck with genanki
my_deck = genanki.Deck(
    1724897887,
    'TestV3v1')

# Translate the list of strings with definition and add as note to anki
translator = Translator()

translations = translator.translate(aList, dest='da')
for translation in translations:
    aNote = genanki.Note(
        model=my_model, fields=[translation.origin, translation.text]
    )
    my_deck.add_note(aNote)

# Output anki file in desired folder
genanki.Package(my_deck).write_to_file(
    '/Users/.../TestV3v1.apkg')
```

This code also executes just fine and generates a file which can be opened in Anki, the card then shows the original word on the front of the flashcards, with the translation on the back.

**My problem**

In order to finish my project, I wish to add a definition to the backside of each card accompanying the translation. I originally thought that I would just have to correct the  my_model = genanki.model(...) variable, by adding another field so that I could just add dictionary.meaning(translation.origin) to the note generator in the for-loop.

However, when trying to add just the definitions to make sure they run smoothly, I run into problems. Consider the code below:

```
for translation in translations:
    aNote = genanki.Note(
        model=my_model, fields=[translation.origin,
                                dictionary.meaning(translation.origin)
                                ]
    )
    my_deck.add_note(aNote)
```

I expected the cards to be printed as usual, with the original word on the frontside and the definition on the backside, but running the full code with this for-loop instead gives me the following error(s):

```
Error: The Following Error occured: list index out of range
Error: The Following Error occured: list index out of range
Error: The Following Error occured: list index out of range
Error: A Term must be only a single word
Error: A Term must be only a single word
Error: A Term must be only a single word
Error: A Term must be only a single word
Error: A Term must be only a single word
Error: The Following Error occured: list index out of range
Error: A Term must be only a single word
Error: A Term must be only a single word
Error: The Following Error occured: list index out of range
Error: The Following Error occured: list index out of range
Error: The Following Error occured: list index out of range
Error: A Term must be only a single word
Error: A Term must be only a single word
Error: A Term must be only a single word
Error: A Term must be only a single word
Error: A Term must be only a single word
Error: A Term must be only a single word
Error: The Following Error occured: list index out of range
Error: A Term must be only a single word
Error: The Following Error occured: list index out of range
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Lehmann/Desktop/XYZ/Programming/Translator/TranslatorProgramv3.py", line 51, in <module>
    '/Users/Lehmann/Desktop/XYZ/Programming/Translator/TestV3v1.apkg')
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/genanki/__init__.py", line 313, in write_to_file
    self.write_to_db(cursor, now_ts)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/genanki/__init__.py", line 331, in write_to_db
    deck.write_to_db(cursor, now_ts)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/genanki/__init__.py", line 267, in write_to_db
    note.write_to_db(cursor, now_ts, self.deck_id)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/genanki/__init__.py", line 228, in write_to_db
    self._format_fields(),        # flds
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/genanki/__init__.py", line 240, in _format_fields
    return '\x1f'.join(self.fields)
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, dict found
```

I suspect it is the part "Expected str instance, dict found" that causes me trouble, however, this is my very first python project and I am not a programmer, so I hope someone out there can help me understand the issue.

BR

Mikkel

Answer (score 3):

always make sure to check what type the the variable is when you are using it. From what I found, using dictionary.meaning(...) changes the type to dictionary. So all you need to do is this:

```
meaning=dictionary.meaning(translation.origin)
meaning_to_string=''.join('{}: {}'.format(key,val) for key,val in meaning.items())

#moving to aNote
aNote=genanki.Note(model=my_model, fields=[translation.origin,meaning_to_string])
```